# Why is my JS random ints generator so wrong when I give him one negative and one positive number?

Tags: javascript, random, integer, int, generator

So I use such script for random int generation inside of range

```
function randomInRange(start, end)
{
  if ((start >= 0) && (end >= 0))
  {
    return Math.round(Math.abs(start) + (Math.random() * (Math.abs(end) - Math.abs(start))));

  }
  else if ((start <= 0) && (end <= 0))
  {
    return 0 - (Math.round(Math.abs(start) + (Math.random() * (Math.abs(end) - Math.abs(start)))));
  }
  else
  {
    return Math.round(((start) + Math.random() * (end - start)));
  }

}
```

You can see it at work [here](http://jsdo.it/oleg.jakushkin/ihFr). for Positive ranges its correct, for negative its correct but I get bad and wrong results for mixed. Why and how to fix it?

I try to use formula like `Math.round(start + Math.random() * (end - start));`

Comment: What's wrong with the formula you have on the bottom, that works with no `if`s and both positives and negatives?

Comment: Your question title is a sentence. Please make it not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found the problem, you're performing algebra on strings (since in your code `$('fnt').value` is the value of an input box, which is a string), not numbers, so things like `+` will end up concatenating strings and not adding their numeric content. In your particular example, you have:

```
Math.round(((start) + Math.random() * (end - start)))
```

Which evaluates to:

```
Math.round((('13') + Math.random() * ('-666' - '13')))
```

Which evaluates to (for example):

```
Math.round("13-339.44615370430984")
```

Since `'13' + '-339.44615370430984'` will be concatenated, and finally the `Math.round` call will return `NaN`

You should have:

```
function randomInRange(start, end) {
  start = Number(start); end = Number(end);
  return Math.round(start + Math.random() * (end - start));
}
```

Or change the values you pass into the function, making sure they're numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Math.round` you will get an uneven distribution.

If you for example ask for numbers between 2 and 4, only the random numbers between 2.0 and 2.5 will be rounded to 2, and only the numbers between 3.5 and 4.0 will be rounded to 4, while the numbers between 2.5 and 3.5 will be rounded to 3. That means that 50% of the numbers will be 3, while only 25% will be 2 and 25% will be 4.

Use `Math.floor` instead to get an even distribution of the random numbers.

You don't have to check for the sign of the `start` and `end`, the expression `end - start + 1` will be the size of the range with the sign different depending on which side of `start` it is.

```
function randomInRange(start, end) {
  if (start > end) start++; else end++;
  return Math.floor((start + Math.random() * (end - start)));
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/guaEp/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/guaEp/1/)

#### Correction:

The expression `end - start + 1` doesn't work if `start` > `end`. The expression `end - start` works if the upper bound is exclusive, i.e. the range -10 to 11 returns numbers between -10 and 10. I added code so that the function takes inclusive upper bound and converts it to an exclusive.

#### Also:

As davin pointed out, you are feeding the function strings, which will make the function concatenate the strings instead of doing arithmetic operations.

Just convert the strings to numbers using the parseInt function:

```
val.innerHTML = randomInRange(parseInt($('fnt').value), parseInt($('lint').value));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm too lazy to find the error in your code, but the calculation can be done much easier:

```
function randomInRange(start, end)
{
    //Extra variables to make it easier to understand
    var rangeBegin = Math.min(start,end);
    var rangeEnd = Math.max(start,end);
    var rangeSize = rangeEnd-rangeBegin+1;    

    var seed = Math.random();
    var result = Math.floor((seed*rangeSize)+rangeBegin);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply

```
function randomInRange(start, end) {
    return Math.round(start + Math.random() * (end - start));
}
```

should work.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tj6Sp/)

---

**UPDATE:** As @Guffa correctly pointed out, distribution will not be even. You can use this:

```
return Math.floor(start-- + Math.random() * (end - start));
```